# Proof verification for FLT when $n=3$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

For:

$$a^3 + b^3 = c^3$$

Why can't I simply take mod 3 ?

The only possibility is when

$a\equiv 0$ (mod 3) and

$b\equiv 0$ (mod 3)

But if this happens then 3 can be taken as a common factor. Keep on doing this and we will arrive at two integers

$\frac {a}{3^n} , \frac {b}{3^n}$

Where 3 is not a common factor. Just like at the beginning, we take mod 3, but since both cannot give 0 (mod 3), it is a contradiction.

What I am asking is if this is a valid proof. Maybe I am missing something fundamental in this. Thanks in advance. I hope proof verification questions like these are accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately not, eg: $2^3=8=2\bmod 3,1^3=1\bmod 3,3^3=0\bmod 3$.

Comment: Why is the only possibility when $a \equiv 0 \pmod 3, b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$? The only condition you get from reducing mod $3$ is that $a + b \equiv c \pmod 3$, from what I can see.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Because that is the only possibility. $0+0=0$ when taken mod 3 on both sides.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Just look at the example I gave in the first comment!

Comment: @almagest $2^3 + 1^3 = 3^2 \neq 3^3$

Comment: Note that $0^3+1^3=1^3$.  So a *pure congruence argument* will probably not work.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Precisely, but $2^3+1^3=3^3\bmod 3$

Comment: see here the proof for the special case n=3
http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51546.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, it is shown that the congruence $a^3+b^3=c^3$ has "non-trivial" solutions modulo $3$. For example, $1^3+2^3\equiv 3^3\pmod{3}$.

Note that $0^3+1^3=1^3$. So the equation $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has an integer solution, with not all the entries equal to $0$. This brings up a useful methodological point. Suppose that we want to show that a Diophantine equation has no solutions except for a couple of "obvious" ones that we have found.

Then an argument based *purely* on congruences is not likely to work. For if it ruled out the existence of a solution, it would also rule out the existence of the solutions we have located. So in such a situation congruential arguments may narrow the range of possibilities, but additional arguments are needed.